# Is there a way avoid a global array?

Tags: c++, arrays

A lab assignment that I have for a beginner C++ class involves printing the squareroot of a series of numbers stored in an array. The program itself works, but my teacher does not want us to use global variables.

```
void assignValue(){
for (int x=0; x<10; x++){
    int num;
    num = rand() % 100 + 1;
    if (num % 2 != 0){
        num += 1;
    }
    arr[x] = num;
}
```

Here's the main method

```
int main() {
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
assignValue();
for (int f = 0; f < 10; f++){
    cout << f << setw(8) << right << arr[f];
    float square = sqrt(arr[f]);
    cout << setw(8) << right << fixed << setprecision(3) << square << endl;
}
```

The arr is a global variable above the main method.

Comment: pass the array to the functions instead of having a global variable.

Comment: Since this is a C++ question you could get fancy: Instead of doing it the C way, passing a pointer and a length, you can pass a reference to the array proper. Make the length a `const size_t` because it is part of the array type. More fancy: Make a template of it (and a comment that you'd love to use a std::vector  but you are not allowed to ;-) ).

Comment: Instead of mentioning that there is a global array, please make a [mre] and show it.

Comment: In this case, you can just inline the `assignValue` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

void assignValue(int arr[], size_t n) {
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      int num;
      num = std::rand() % 100 + 1;
      if (num % 2 != 0) {
          num += 1;
      }
      arr[i] = num;
  }
}

int main() {
  const size_t size = 10;
  int arr[size];
  std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));
  assignValue(arr, size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
      std::cout << i << std::setw(8) << std::right << arr[i];
      float square = std::sqrt(arr[i]);
      std::cout << std::setw(8) << std::right << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << square << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion for the function taking an array reference:

```
// headers omitted (you'll need additionally iomanip, ctime, cstdlib, cmath)

// The constant is necessary because the function takes 
// a reference to an array *of this specific size*
const size_t ARR_SIZE = 10;

// Take a reference to the array (the array is not copied)
void assignValue(int (&arr)[ARR_SIZE]) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) {
    int num = rand() % 100 + 1;
    if (num % 2 != 0) {
      num += 1;
    }
    arr[i] = num;
  }
}
```

You call the function simply with

```
int main() 
{
  int arr[ARR_SIZE];
  // [...]
  assignValue(arr);
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a more Core Guideline compliant way of doing this as no pointers, or size information is needed.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void assignValue(T (&arr)[N])
{
    for (auto &elem : arr) {
        elem = rand() % 100 + 1;

        if (elem % 2 != 0) {
            elem += 1;
        }
    }
}

auto
main() -> int
{
    constexpr const auto ARRAY_SIZE = 10;

    int arr[ARRAY_SIZE];
    assignValue(arr);

    return 0;
}
```